# JComboBox only show one item from database

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, jcombobox

I'm trying to display database item into a `JComboBox` and this is my code.

```
public static void checkItemName(){
    Connection conn = SQLite.SQLite();
    String sql = "select itemname from item";
    try{
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (resultSet.next()){
            String list = resultSet.getString("itemname");
            purcItemName.addItem(list);
            conn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException lol){
        System.out.println(lol.toString());
    }

}
```

I did declare `static JComboBox purcItemName;` and `purcItemName = new JComboBox();`

The method/function will be called then user press login button.

**The problem I'm having now is that, it only shows one item while my database has multiple items.**

Anyone got an idea why?

Comment: *"I did declare `static JComboBox purcItemName;`"* remove the `static` declaration as well as the same for that method.  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"it only shows one item while my database has multiple items"* How many times does it loop on `resultSet.next()`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson solved, thanks!

Comment: Yes I noticed. Glad you two got it sorted. :) Good call on accepting the answer, BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Vector v = new Vector();
        while (resultSet.next()){
            String list = resultSet.getString("itemname");
            v.add(list);

        }
        conn.close();
        purcItemName.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(v));
```

store the data you got from database in a vector object and once that is completed set the vector object in your combobox as a new model. try this one
and **don't close the connection *inside* your loop.**

Comment: solved, thanks! And yeah, sorry forgotten I'm using while loop.

Comment: While I appreciate the API requirements, but we really shouldn't be using `Vector` unless you have a specific use case for it

Answer (score 0):

you are closing connection inside resultSet.next() check, put the conn.close() outside, to the end